# build error in jenkins.Fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, git, cordova, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build application with xcode,but i am getting some error messages in jenkins  as the Cordova files has not been found

I add $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

[Search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4V28.png)

and i still get the error

[the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zeY1.png)